# PHP: Given a number, return no more than a given number

Tags: php, numbers

I wasn't quite sure how to put this but here is what I'm trying to achieve.

Given a number like 20 I want to retrieve no more than 100 out of that number.

```
Examples:
20 - I want to return 20
100 - I want to return 100
200 - I want to return 100
0 - I want to return 0
```

So it is never more than 100.

Comment: `$number = $number <= 100 ? $number : 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function:

```
// $in is the input number
// $out is the output number
$out = min($in, 100);

// Examples:
$in = 20;
$out = min($in, 100);
echo $out; // prints out 20

$in = 200;
$out = min($in, 100);
echo $out; // prints out 100

$in = 100;
$out = min($in, 100);
echo $out; // prints out 100
```

Comment: Hey this is perfect and short! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?php
 function standard_compare($number){
    if ($number <= 100) {
        return $number; 
    }else{
        return 100;
    }
 }
?>
```